# How can I find out what enums are defined by a class?

Tags: java

I know I can get the public static members of a class by doing something like:

`obj.getClass().getFields()`

but this doesn't get me the enums.  I'd like to be able to get them from the Class object returned by the getClass method.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Turned into a community wiki as it looks like there's scope for a fair amount of expansion, e.g. to include tackline's comments. No sense in me just transcribing comments when everyone could be expanding it.)

Do you mean enums nested within a top-level class? If so, use `Class.getDeclaredClasses()` and iterate through the results seeing if any of the nested classes are enums. The simplest way of testing each nested class is to use `Class.isEnum()`; if you want to iterate through the values within the enum then `Class.getEnumConstants()` is the way to go.

Comment: Just a remark, you can use getClasses() or getDeclaredClasses() depending on your needs.

Comment: @Alexander: I suspect that getDeclaredClasses() is almost always the way to go, so I edited the answer.

Comment: I retracted my answer because this one is now more general, and sounds like a very sensible approach to me. :-)

Comment: If it's a specialised enum constant you'll need to `getSuperclass`.

Comment: public enum En {
    X() { public String toString() { return ""; } }
    ;
    static {
         System.err.println(X.getClass().getEnumConstants());
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

obj.getClass().getEnumConstants()

Comment: getEnumConstants will return the enum 'elements' defined by this class if it is an Enum (see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants() )